# Why curses.initscr() takes no effect in Windows 11 Command Prompt?

Tags: python, windows, terminal, curses

I´m trying to write some programs in Python with windows.curses but when I run the program nothing happens. The code is:

```
import curses
from curses import wrapper

def main(scr):
    scr.initscr()
    scr.clear()
    scr.addstr(20, 20, "Hello World!")
    scr.refresh()
    scr.getch()

wrapper(main)
```

When I open a CMD windows and I run "python3 curses_test.py", nothing happens and no error is reported. The prompt just jump to a new line.

Anyone already have this problem? I´m using Windows 11 Professional, Python 3.12.1 and windows.curses 2.3.2.

In linux the same code works perfectly.

Comment: Windows doesn't use the "python3" name though, it's just python and your PATH tells windows which default executable to use if you have multiple versions installed?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, in Windows I use "py curses_test.py" (python3 works in linux).

Comment: if I create a venv, install `windows.curses` v2.3.2 in that, and then copy-paste your code and try to run it, I get `AttributeError: '_curses.window' object has no attribute 'initscr'` for the `scr.initscr()` line.

Comment: I opened the Python console and typed "import curses" and after that I typed "scr = curses.initscr()" and after hit ENTER the Python console just exited without messages and returned to CMD prompt. My impression is the code break in initiscr() line and just abort without error messages...

Comment: If I reproduce those steps, the cmd buffer gets cleared and I get an "empty screen", and if I ctrl-c I get back to the Python repl. Are you using a virtual environment? Because if not, you probably want to set that up so that global python things don't interfere with _this_ code.

Comment: I´m using a Samsung Laptop with Windows 11 Pro. I´ll try it in a virtual environment. Thanks.

Comment: ... I'm talking about a _Python_ virtual environment, as covered over on https://python.land/virtual-environments/virtualenv etc., not a "virtual machine" with a different operating system =) You create a venv, then you activate it so you're now "locked into that venv", you install your dependencies with `python -m pip install ...` and then you run your code with `python ...` and things will now run isolated to that virtual environment, without your global OS settings interfering.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know on Windows, it is working on iOS. Try this:

```
import curses

import time

scr = curses.initscr()

def main(scr):
    
    
    scr.clear()
    
    scr.addstr(20, 20, "Hello World!")
    
    scr.refresh()
    
    time.sleep(5)
    
    scr.clear()
    
    scr.refresh()
    
    time.sleep(5)
    
    scr.addstr(20, 20, "Hello World! 2 ")
    
    print('print(scr) : ' , scr)
    
    scr.refresh()
    
main(scr)
```

and check if it behaves differently.

Comment: I´ve tryed with time.sleep(50) and it didn´t work too. My impression is that the code abort after the curses.initscr() because the time.sleep() takes no effect. The code return to the prompt line without "sleep", but with no error messages.